# Secure communication between InstallHandler and third party application

Tags: apex, integration, session, postinstall, authorization

During the installation of our package we need to fetch data (related to the installer organization) from a third party system (integration part of our solution).

Like stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm)  there is no access to a session-id in an InstallationHandler. So it is not possible to use it to authenticate the user and to obtain informations like organisation id through the API.

What is the best approach without an instance-url/session-id to reliable verify the identity (org id) for a request that was originated in an InstallHandler?